# Ignore Ant warning with comment

Tags: eclipse, ant, build, ivy

I have the very easy Ant example here that produces Eclipse to report a warning:

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="path.pmd" organisation="pmd" module="pmd" revision="4.3" conf="default" inline="true" />
<taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" classpathref="path.pmd" />
```

The problem reported is:

```
Description                     Resource    Path    Location    Type
Reference path.pmd not found.   build.xml   /MyPrj  line 20     Ant Buildfile Problem
```

Now it is quite clear what is happening here. Ant does not see path.pmd defined in the ivy's cachepath task and creates the warning. **Now I would like to ignore this warning.** However, I don't want to go ignore the warning by using the Ant preferences in Eclipse. I know that is easy, but this will also mean that one day when I really have the missing reference I will not get the warning.

Does Ant have comment style ignoring? Like in PMD when you can use //NOPMD to ignore any warning on specified line. If there is, please enlighten me :)

If not, is there any other way to remove this warning from this specific line in the Ant build file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think preferences is the key even if you don't want to, check out this, maybe you will find something else in few links away:

[How to tell Eclipse to ignore errors in an Ant build.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227028/how-to-tell-eclipse-to-ignore-errors-in-an-ant-build-xml)

I found this from Knots:

"Another workaround (less drastic than disable all validation/problem reporting): Go to Window->preferences->Ant->Problems tab. Add "build.xml" to the ignore list..."

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no.

It is, however, possible to use properties to switch targets on/off as follows:

```
<target name="resolve-ivy" if="use.ivy">
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="path.pmd"....
</target>

<target name="resolve-ant" unless="use.ivy">
    <path id="path.pmd">
        <pathelement location="/path/to/pmd/jar/pmd.jar"/>
    </path>
</target>

<target name="create-tasks" depends="resolve-ivy,resolve-ant">
    <taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" classpathref="path.pmd" />
</target>
```

So if the property "use.ivy" is set then your build will use ivy to download the build dependencies.

I have a number of observations....

## Is this warning really ignorable?

Why would you use two mechanisms to manage your build's classpaths?

If you're using Eclipse perhaps investigate using the [Eclipse plugin](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/) and an external ivy.xml to track your project's dependencies. This approach would sync the classpaths used by both ANT and Eclipse.

## PMD modules in Maven Central

ivy is pulling the wrong module from Maven Central. The latest revision of PMD is 5.0.1:

- http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22pmd%22

I would suggest the following alternative ivy task configuration

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="path.pmd">
   <dependency org="net.sourceforge.pmd" name="pmd" rev="5.0.1" conf="default"/>
</ivy:cachepath>
```

NOTE:

- This syntax requires the [latest version of ivy 2.3.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.ivy%7Civy%7C2.3.0-rc2%7Cjar)

## Have you considered Sonar?

An arguably simpler way to enable PMD would be to use the [Sonar ANT task](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Sonar+Ant+Task), which will also analyze your code using Findbugs and Checkstyle.

This task can also be retrieved using ivy:

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="path.sonar">
    <dependency org="org.codehaus.sonar-plugins" name="sonar-ant-task" rev="2.0" conf="conf"/>
</ivy:cachepath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window->preferences->Ant->Problems tab. Add "build.xml" to the ignore list.
This should solve your problem.